# jQuery short code for persudo

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to say my div child li:nth-child(1) - li:nth-child(5) hide first then when the user clicks some button, show child(6) - 10.
Below is a longer version of the code:

```
$('.history_presss ul li').hide();
$('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(1)').show();
$('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(2)').show();
$('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(3)').show();
$('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(4)').show();
$('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(5)').show();
$('ul.jPag-pages li:nth-child(1)').click(function(){
  $('.history_presss ul li').hide();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(1)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(2)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(3)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(4)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(5)').show();
});
$('ul.jPag-pages li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
  $('.history_presss ul li').hide();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(6)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(7)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(8)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(9)').show();
  $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(10)').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use

`:lt(), :gt()` instead of `nth-child()`

for example

```
$('.history_presss ul li:lt(5)').show();
$('.history_presss ul li:gt(4)').hide();
```

don't forget `:lt()` and `:gt()` takes index.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just loop through them with a for-loop?

Create an index variable and add it in your code.

Pseudocode:

```
$('.history_presss ul li').hide();
   for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')').show();

        $('ul.jPag-pages li:nth-child(1)').click(function(){
            $('.history_presss ul li').hide();
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
               $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')').show();
        })
        $('ul.jPag-pages li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
            $('.history_presss ul li').hide();
            for (int i = 6; i < 11; i++)
               $('.history_presss ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')').show();

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the :lt() and :gt() selectors?

- http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

The code could look like this:

```
$('.history_presss ul li').hide();
$('.history_presss ul li:lt(4)').show();
$('ul.jPag-pages li:nth-child(1)').on('click', function(){
    $('.history_presss ul li').hide();
    $('.history_presss ul li:lt(4)').show();
})
$('ul.jPag-pages li:nth-child(2)').on('click', function(){
    $('.history_presss ul li').hide();
    $('.history_presss ul li:gt(4)').show();
})
```

But be aware, that the count starts with '0' and lt is "less then" (not less then or equal).

On a side note:
If you're using a current jQuery you should switch to "on()" for binding actions.